# How to fix up Xcode function "Filling the gap"

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

I have a problem with My XCode 4.3.2.
XCode has the function "Filling the gap".
We type 'uil', XCode shows 'UILabel' text with pale white color and pulldown menu.

But my Xcode doesn't work as I mentioned above.
In a blog, says
1. Open organizer.
2. Select tab 'Projects'.
3. Select your project name.
4. Tap the 'delete' button with 'Derived Data' section.

I did mentioned above, it looks like working well.
But after a short time, it doesn't work again.
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer for you, but you may get better results searching for the term "code completion", as that's what that feature is called in English.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Mr. Ken Thomases.
This is the first time writing English question.